# What do non-standard cardinalities look like?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, axioms, nonstandard-models

The Von Neumann universe $V$ satisfies ZFC, and there are other models within $V$ that are non-standard and satisfy ZFC. If we look at one of these non-standard models $M$ with a non-standard model of PA $P$, then internally to $M$ we have a notion of 'numbers' in $P$.

Consider a non-standard number $H$ in $P$. I want to understand what a set $A$ (in the non-standard model of ZFC $M$) of cardinality $H$ looks like. What will such a set's external (i.e., w.r.t. $V$) cardinality be? What about a set $B$ of cardinality $H+1$? It seems like you could just take the union of $A$ with some element of $P$ not in $A$ to get a set of cardinality $H+1$.

I am seeing a few ways to resolve this:

1. Sets of nonstandard cardinalities don't exist within $M$.
2. $A$ and $B$ exist in $M$; they have different cardinalities within $M$. However, with respect to $V$, they are both infinite and of the same cardinality. The only reason they have different cardinalities in $M$ is that the bijection between $A$ and $B$ is not within $M$.
3. $A$ and $B$ are infinite and have different external cardinalities, but you can't take the union of $A$ and some element of $P$ to get something of cardinality $H+1$ for some reason.
4. $A$ and $B$ are infinite and have different external cardinalities, but taking the union of $A$ and some element of $P$ is somehow externally not just adding one thing to $A$, but enough things to change its cardinality.

Which of these, if any, is the right answer?

Comment: Let $\mathbb M=(M,E)$ be a non-standard model that satisfies $(ZFC,\in). $....If $h,x \in M$  then, because  $\mathbb M$ satisfies Extensionality and Union , we  have $(\{x\})^{\mathbb M}=\{x\}$ and $(h\cup  \{x\})^{\mathbb M}=h\cup \{x\}.$.... But if $h$ is a non-standard positive integer of $\mathbb M$ (or of $P$) then $h$ is an infinite set so the cardinal of $h\cup \{x\}$ equals the cardinal of $h$.  However  if $\neg (xEh).$... (i.e. $\mathbb M\Vdash (x\not \in h$)...then there does not exist $f\in M$ such that  $\mathbb M\Vdash$ "$f$ is a bijection from $h$ to $h\cup \{x\}$".

Comment: Sorry, please allow me to ask a stupid question (I'm a beginner with mathematical logic): doesn't every model of ZF define $\mathbb{N}$ to be the standard model of PA? The definition $\mathbb{N}$ with which I'm familier is the insection of all inductive subsets of any given inductive set (which exists by the axiom of infinity). This must be the standard model of PA since every nonstandard one contains the standard one which is an inductive set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 2 is correct: $M$ doesn't see the bijection that exists externally (= in $V$).

Specifically, let's take $P$ to be $M$'s actual version of $\mathbb{N}$ (I think this is what you had in mind anyways) and make our $A$ and $B$ really simple: let $a$ be some nonstandard natural number in $M$, and set $A=\{n\in\mathbb{N}^M: M\models n<a\}$ and $B=\{n\in\mathbb{N}^M: M\models n\le a\}=A\cup\{a\}$. Then:

- In $M$, both $A$ and $B$ are finite and $A\subsetneq B$; so in $M$ there is no bijection between $A$ and $B$.
- In $V$, both $A$ and $B$ are infinite, and $B$ is $A$ plus one element, so there is a bijection $f:A\rightarrow B$ **in the true model $V$**.

Another example of this phenomenon, which doesn't involve arithmetic, is: suppose $M$ is a countable transitive submodel of $V$ (ok fine, we need a weak hypothesis to guarantee such an $M$ exists, but ignore that for now). Then $\omega_1^M$ is an ordinal which in $V$ is countable; the reason $M$ doesn't see a bijection between $\omega_1^M$ and $\omega^M$ (exercise: $\omega^M=\omega$, since $M$ is **transitive** and hence well-founded) is because the countability of $\omega_1^M$ is only seen outside of $M$.

---

Incidentally, the following is a great exercise for becoming comfortable with internal vs. external reasoning.

> Suppose that $M$ is a countable *elementary* (not transitive) submodel of $V$. Show that (i) $\omega_1^M=\omega_1$ and $\omega^M=\omega$, (ii) $Ord^M$ is not closed downwards in $V$ (and so we can conclude that there are no countable elementary transitive submodels of $V$), but (iii) $\omega_1\cap M$ is closed downwards.

Part (i) is immediate from elementarity and part (ii) follows from part (i); part (iii), however, takes some thought.

This isn't an exercise about nonstandard models, of course - everything we're talking about is well-founded - but it is all about being careful about what model believes what statement.

Comment: Do you really need choice for the bijection in $V$? Can't you just map $0$ to $a$ and shift the standard naturals (which $V$ can see) down by $1$?

Comment: Also, in the example (not the exercise), you didn't mean to say "elementary", right? (Such a model doesn't exist, by the exercise!)

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, on both points. For the former, though, what I was getting at was the statement "An infinite set + one element is in bijection with the original infinite set" is not ZF-provable; but you're right that the particular application here is.